# Estimating a probability with converging moments

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let me rephrase my question.

If you look at the random variable $X$ which simply picks a random integer between $1$ and $N$ (distributed uniformly) and now look at the inequality
$$
t^k \cdot \rm{Prob}[X \geq t] \leq \rm{E}[X^k]
$$
it mostly doesn't say anything interesting. But when $t$ is sufficiently large, say slightly less than $N$, then for some values of $k$ large enough, you obtain a pretty good bound on the probability (which of course is really easy to compute in this case). I do understand what is going on in this case, since here $E[X^k]$ will roughly be $(1/N)N^k$ which will give a decent bound on the probability.

What I'd like to know is:

- when does this happen?
- can we say what kind of values of $t$ will yield tight bounds (as $k$ grows larger)
- do we get to say something for any random variable?

It just seems interesting to me that such a thing gives sometimes a reasonable bound on a probability (for some good values of $t$ and $k$) (while clearly, most of the times gives nothing interesting) given that this makes absolutely no assumption on the random variable or the probability space.

== Older version of the question ==

I'm looking at this fairly obvious bound: Let $X$ be a positive real random variable, then, for any $t$ and $k$, we have that
$$
t^k \cdot \rm{Prob}[X \geq t] \leq \rm{E}[X^k]
$$

I'm interested in estimating the probability (so I'm assuming to either know the moments or have a good estimation of them).

In most cases, the estimation you obtain on the probability is pretty bad, but it seems that there are cases where you obtain something very good.

I'm not that familiar with general knowledge on moments in probability theory, so is this a classical problem with a good description of what works and doesn't work?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: The question I'm asking is: what kind of choice for $t$ gives me interesting bounds for suitable values of $k$?

Comment: This is quite vague, what are "interesting bounds"?

Answer (score 3):

Using the reduced random variable $Y=(X/t)^{1/k}$, one sees that there is only one inequality here, which is
$$
\Pr(Y\geqslant1)\leqslant E[Y].
$$
Now, this is optimal in the sense that, taking the supremum over every nonnegative random variable $Y$ such that $E[Y]=1$,
$$
\sup_Y\frac{\Pr(Y\geqslant1)}{E[Y]}=1.
$$
On the other hand, for every $X$ integrable,
$$
\inf_t\,\frac{t\Pr(X\geqslant t)}{E[X]}=\lim_{t\to\infty}\frac{t\Pr(X\geqslant t)}{E[X]}=0.
$$